# UWF Filter - Power off PC without shutdown

Tags: windows, uwf

I am using UWF Filter on Windows 10 PC to protect the C disk and to be able to turn off the PC without shutdown procedure.
If the PC is turned off (power removed) without shutdown, although the filter is enabled, when the PC starts a recovery blue screen is displayed with error 0xc0000001. The files are not damaged because the filter is active but the recovery page is displayed.
Is there any way to avoid it?

Below the UWF configuration:
OVERLAY SETTINGS
Type:                  Disk
Maximum size:          8192 MB
Warning Threshold:     7000 MB
Critical Threshold:    6500 MB
Read Only Media:       OFF
Freespace Passthrough: ON
Persistent:            OFF
Reset Mode:            N/A
Reset Saved Mode:      N/A

VOLUME SETTINGS
Volume 3ee37432-0000-0000-0000-803500000000 [C:]
Volume state:     Protected
Volume ID:        3ee37432-0000-0000-0000-803500000000
Swapfile:         0 MB

```
File Exclusions:
```

Next Session Exclusions for Volume 3ee37432-0000-0000-0000-803500000000 [C:]
*** No exclusions

I tried to configure UWF filter overlay with RAM and Disk but nothing change.